# Html head flushing with freemarker

Tags: html, spring-mvc, freemarker, flush

I have a Spring MVC web application that uses freemarker as the template language. I am currently working on the changes to flush the html head section rather than buffering the whole html and flushing at the end. I tried setting the [auto_flush freemarker setting](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/core/Configurable.html#setSetting%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to false and used freemarker's builtin <#flush> directive as below, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
common-header.ftl
<head>
 .......
</head>
<#flush>

page.ftl
<#include "common-header.ftl" />
<body>
 .......
</body>
```

I would appreciate your help with this. Also, per the [API documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/core/Configurable.html#setAutoFlush%28boolean%29), autoFlush() seems to only work for pages which aren't composed with #include statements and require multiple Template.process() methods. If that's correct, should i write a custom template processor to handle the head and body sections in my page ? Any pointers would be helpful.

Update:

Tried using [FreeMarkerView.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/1.2.1/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker/FreeMarkerView.java) as the view class as it uses the default writer (PrinterWriter) of HttpServletResponse to process the writer. This doesn't work either though PrinterWriter does support flush() and the <#flush> freemarker directive in my template doesn't seem to be invoking this.

Tried extending the FreeMarkerView class to wrap the PrinterWriter inside a BufferedWriter, and that doesn't work as well.

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="suffix"><value>.ftl</value></property>
    <property name="contentType"><value>text/html; charset=utf-8</value></property>
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView"/>
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers"><value>true</value></property>
</bean>
```

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: How do you test this?

Comment: Aleksandr M@, can you please elaborate on that ? I tested by deploying the web application and requesting the html pages which are generated using Freemarker.

Comment: "but that doesn't seem to work" what makes you think that?

Comment: Raedwald@, I have confirmed this by looking at the Firebug's Net Panel. The html I am trying to flush the head for, is still returned in whole as a single response (ie. a single giant purple bar followed by a single green bar). With flush, I would expect to head to be returned first and the body to be returned later after a while. This wasn't the case though.

Answer (score 2):

`<#flush>` simply calls `Writer.flush()` on the `Writer` that was given to `Template.process`. If, for example, that `Writer` is a `StringWriter`, the `flush()` call will not do nothing of course. The thing that passes the `Writer` to FreeMarker will have to ensure that that `Writer` does the right thing when its `flush()` method is called.

`auto_flush` is unrelated to your problem. (But you misunderstand the API docs. `auto_flush` is always supported. The docs describe the case when you want to set it to `false`.)

Comment: Thanks ddekany@. Do you know which Writer does Spring's [FreeMarkerConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker/FreeMarkerConfigurer.html) use ? And, if there's an easy way to switch the writer to something like BufferedWriter so that adding the <#flush> directive invokes the BufferedWriter's flush method ?

Comment: I don't know Spring MVC much. But `FreeMarkerConfigurer` seems to deal with building the FreeMarker `Configuration` object only, which doesn't influence what the `Writer` will be. A different `Writer` may be passed to each `Template.process` call, so it's not a global setting in FreeMarker.

Comment: The Writer I have (accessed through org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView) is org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper$SaveContextPrintWriter which seems to delegate to org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter

Comment: Goose@, how did you access the writer through org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView? I do not see any methods in this API which takes in a writer. I would appreciate if you can share this snippet of your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the original question but to @soontobeared comment. I was never notified about your comment so sorry for the late response.

I'm using a buffered view during development so I can catch various exception and output debug etc.. This will give access to the Writer. I'm using Spring 3.2 and FreeMarker 2.3.

BufferedFreeMarkerView.java

```
package com.example.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView;

import freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException;
import freemarker.template.SimpleHash;
import freemarker.template.Template;
import freemarker.template.TemplateException;

public class BufferedFreeMarkerView extends FreeMarkerView {

    @Override
    protected void processTemplate(Template template, SimpleHash model,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, TemplateException {
        StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter(50000);
        try {
            template.process(model, buffer);
        } catch (TemplateException e) {
            logger.warn(e.getMessage() + "\n" + e.getFTLInstructionStack(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage() + "\n"
                    + e.getFTLInstructionStack(), e);
        } // ommited more catches

        try (Writer out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.write(buffer.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

BufferedFreeMarkerViewResolver.java

```
package com.example.web;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver;

public class BufferedFreeMarkerViewResolver extends FreeMarkerViewResolver {

    /**
     * 
     */
    public BufferedFreeMarkerViewResolver() {
        setViewClass(requiredViewClass());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    protected Class requiredViewClass() {
        return BufferedFreeMarkerView.class;
    }

}
```

From spring dispatcher context

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="com.example.web.BufferedFreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
    <property name="allowSessionOverride" value="true"/>
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
    <property name="exposeRequestAttributes" value="true"/>
    <property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true"/>
    <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="rc"/>
</bean>
```